# Грань между разработчиком программ и разработчиком компиляторов

Tags: c++

В последнее время очень много обсуждений об экономии на спичах, как привести ту или иную конструкцию в move семантике, всякие проблемы конкатенации строк с использованием .reserve и счетчике строк etc.

Где та самая грань, между разработчиком программ и разработчиком компиляторов? 
Что должен знать рядовой разработчик о языке? 
Ведь читать весь стандарт и разбираться в различных тонкостях нужно только разработчикам компиляторов?
Или хорошо программировать на c++ не получится не читая весь стандарт?

Т.е. о чем должен знать рядовой программист, а что оставить разработчикам компиляторов и оптимизаторов?

Comment: Хороший мастер в любом деле должен знать свой инструмент досконально. Не могу понять тех, кто пытается понять где та грань, где нужно остановится. На мой взгляд этой грани не существует. Ты должен знать всё, что можно. Иначе какой ты программист? P.S. Я голосовал за закрытие данного вопроса, как слишком широкого. Это всё болтология, тут ответа дать нельзя. Хотите поболтать - добро пожаловать в чат.

Comment: Жалко, что метки [tag:дзен] не осталось.

Comment: @VladD, это же руСО. Нужно не "дзен", нужно "скрепы"

Comment: @ixSci: «скрепы» не несут оттенка созерцательности :) А кстати, _какой_ оттенок несут скрепы? В отрыве от политики.

Comment: @VladD, не знаю. На мой взгляд такой же как и дзен. Мало кто понимает, что это значит, что то, что другое и наделяет его как раз тем смыслом, какой нужен. Типо stuff, thing и issue из буржуйского наречия

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, на мой вкус, дзен у нас означает (ну, когда-то означал) вопрос о смысле основ, далёкий от практики.

Comment: @ixSci, в таком случаи нужно думать над каждым действием учитывая архитектуру проекта, архитектуру процессора, компилятора, отпитимизатора? Так и до паранойи недалеко.
Также работая всегда на gcc и вдруг приходиться перейти на проект на котором используется clang, надо полностью шерстить все отличия того или иного компилятора?

Comment: @arukasa: На мой вкус, специфику компилятора учить не стоит (хотя я помню, что gcc доопределяет переполнение знакового целого). А вот специфику стандарта — да :-\

Comment: @arukasa, нужно учитывать ровно столько информации, сколько необходимо для задачи. Это не отменяет того, что нужно знать и то, что к этой задаче применять не надо. Лучше знать и не применять, чем не знать и, соответственно, не применять. Каждый сам для себя решает.

Comment: @VladD, "дзен" давно лепять везде. По поводу и без оного. Предлагаю не засорять больше дзеном сие пространство. Это вопрос для флудилки

Comment: @ixSci: [tag:дзен].

Comment: @arukasa Эта грань существует лишь в описании вакансий.:) В одной вакансии, например, написано, что программист должен разбираться в методах построения компиляторов, а в другой вакансии может быть написано, что программист должен быть экспертом по C++, хотя вакансия никакой разработки компиляторов не предполагает.:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, а общепринятое опредление эксперта c++ какое?

Comment: @arukasa В моем предыдущем комментарии я описал требование из одной вакансии. И таких вакансий, где написано, что требуется эксперт по C++, можно встретить немало. Что касается понятия эксперта в моем понимании, то это авторитетный, широко известный, открытый для других программистов специалист, который принимает активное участие в обсуждении стандарта C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, нету однозначной границы. Многие вещи можно улучшать до бесконечности. Например, те же копии можно отоптимизировать при помощи move-семантики, вычисления можно вынести на этап компиляции при помощи «шаблонной магии», расходы на конкатенацию можно обойти, зарезервировав память заранее. Частично это проблема языка и «дырявых» абстракций, частично — недостаточно умный оптимизатор.

Границу каждый устанавливает для себя, исходя из своих эстетических предпочтений и практических задач. Например, если код представляет собой бизнес-логику, то в нём низкоуровневые оптимизации смотрятся не на месте, и кроме того ненужным образом усложняют и замедляют разработку.

Поскольку язык большой, программисты обычно знают только часть общей картины, которая попадается им при разработке. Те, кто занимается низкоуровневым кодом и битовыжиманием, часто плохо разбираются в семантике исключений или там многопоточности. Те, кто занимается lock-free-структурами и знают модель памяти до тонкостей, вполне могут плавать в вопросах упаковки структур или шаблонной магии. А те, кто умеет вычислять md5 на этапе компиляции, вполне могут не знать о внутреннем формате и накладных расходах на множественное наследование или плавать в деталях name resolution.

Язык C++ имеет тенденцию к большому акценту на «мелкую» эффективность, поэтому мне кажется, разрабатывая на нём, стоит уделить таким оптимизациям больше внимания.